# Overwrite existing file with Applescript

Tags: applescript

I have a short applescript that exports the bibliographic info from Papers3.app. It's very simple. However, it works the first time when no output file exists. However, if I want to update the output file (by overwriting it), it doesn't work.

Is there something specific I need to tell Applescript to overwrite the current file if it already exists?

```
tell application "Papers"
    set outFile to "/Users/alex/Dropbox/Papers3_Citations/Bibliography-Master.bib"
    export ((every publication item) as list) to outFile
end tell
```

Comment: How about deleting it first if it already exists?

Answer (score 0):

First check for and delete the *file*, then export it:

```
set outFile to "/Users/alex/Dropbox/Papers3_Citations/Bibliography-Master.bib"

tell application "System Events" to if (exists file outFile) then delete file outFile

tell application "Papers" to export ((every publication item) as list) to outFile
```

**NOTE: The *file* is immediately deleted and not placed in the Trash!**

---

If you want to be safe, then use **Finder** to place the *file* in the **Trash**.

```
set outFile to "/Users/alex/Dropbox/Papers3_Citations/Bibliography-Master.bib"

set itExists to application "System Events"'s (exists file outFile)
if itExists then
    set thisFile to POSIX file outFile as alias
    tell application "Finder" to move thisFile to trash
end if

tell application "Papers" to export ((every publication item) as list) to outFile
```